# problem with addactionlistener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have this code:

```
 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                int x = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
                if(x >=0 && x<=6)
                {
                    JButton button[] = new JButton[31];
                    for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
                    {
                        button[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                        button[i].addActionListener(this);
                        add(button[i]);


                    }

                }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

But `button[i].addactionlistener(this)` gives me this error:

```
addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener) in javax.swing.AbstractButton
 cannot be applied to (<anonymous java.awt.event.ItemListener>)
```

How do I solve this?

```
 I think this refer to jcombobox
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your class `implement ActionListener`.

Edit to add: Initially, I missed the phrase "anonymous" in the error message. That leads me to believe that this code resides inside of an anonymous class declaration.
Try replacing

```
button[i].addActionListener(this)
```

with

```
button[i].addActionListener(mcalendar.this)
```

Comment: Can you post your class header? I.e., `class foo extends x implements y`? Also, make sure that `this` refers to the class you think it's referring to.

Comment: public class mcalendar extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ ... }

Comment: OK, then I'm guessing that code snippet you posted is inside of an anonymous class declaration, and hence this doesn't refer to the this you think it does. Try replacing `button[i].addactionlistener(this)` with `button[i].addactionlistener(mcalendar.this)`.

Answer (score 2):

ah, you have an anonymous inner class for ItemListener.

try

```
button[i].addActionListener(mcalendar.this);
```